# Should academic arguments be used to convince someone to accept a PR

Tags: contributor

I contribute to an open source webgl library. A PR has been proposed that solves a problem, introduces a new feature to the library, and places some properties on some class FOO.

I didn't like the placement of that property as i feel it' better suited for BAR. The pattern can be seen as an anti-pattern according to some principles.

I checked out the branch from the PR, refactored it the way i suggested and ended up with 30% less code, and 30% less files being touched, while not breaking the pattern related principles.

I was told that in the case of this library, it's valid to not follow the principle.

I'm a bit confused by the rejection of such an argument (follow a principle). I thought that literature can be cited as sort of an absolute truth, proof.

How can i address this and what should be my expectations?

I can see:

> Well, several decades of CS research seems to disagree with you

As offensive.

Comment: Wonder if the PR would've been accepted if you hadn't offered it up as a solution to a violation of a best practices guideline and instead just offered it up as a reduction in code size and complexity ...

Comment: unfortunately not, i reached out to academia as a last resort

Comment: It was argued that despite the code reduction, the pattern goes against the (anti?) pattern of the library already in place. `.foo`, `.bar` and `.baz` have historically been scattered between super and sub classes, in order to keep it consistent, it shouldn't be applied to `.baz` straight away. The argument is for a larger PR to address the placement of all the props that may be misplaced. But this i think would move much slower than just properly placing a new one in the first place.

Comment: Why the downvote, can you help improve the question or state why it should be removed?

Comment: The key here is in "best practices" not "holy word"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is asking us to weigh in on a technical discussion that is completely orthogonal to open source development, and therefore off topic.

Comment: Is there a more generic question that can be extracted from this? The technical aspect is irrelevant, its relevant that there is a best practice suggested somewhere, and that it's not being adhered to.

Comment: I tried to trim it a bit and make it more generic. I think the key to my confusion was the term `best practices`, and the answer sort of explains that.

Comment: If the program is open source, you always have the option to make your own fork, follow the best practices in your fork, and maintain it yourself. However, if you want the current maintainer to accept your changes, best practices are ultimately irrelevant; follow the maintainer's rules, guidelines, expectations, etc. "When in Rome, do as the Romans do..." Even if you disagree with them and even if there is absolute proof that they are wrong.

Comment: Yup, the more layers I peel the clearer it gets. It's not really `do as the romans do` but more `do as the Duce says`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that literature can be cited as sort of an absolute truth, proof.

Honestly, that's ridiculous. Just like anything else, SOLID is a set of guidelines which have been found to be *generally* applicable and useful - but not universally. It may be the are good reasons to break the guidelines in the case.

For what it's worth, what you're doing here is [argument from authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID

Comment: Is there more of a burden on one side? Everything i read was formatted in such a way to make it sound that breaking away from any such principle is the thing that needs to be justified, while just adhering to the principle does not.

Comment: What else can i use to say `There aren't good reasons to break the guidelines in this case` if not cite the academic guideline?

Comment: Practically, the burden is on the person without commit permissions to convince the person with commit permissions. You can argue academic points about where the burden "should" lie as much as you want, but you won't even get fake Internet points for it.

Comment: Oh, that actually explains it. I was going to ask that as my next question :) commit permissions win over non commit permissions regardless of what academia says.

Comment: @pailhead, there is one principle that trumps all others. That is the principle of consistency. A codebase that violates the SOLID principles in a consistent manner is generally more maintainable (has fewer surprises) than a codebase that applied the SOLID principle in an inconsistent manner.

Comment: That was the argument that was given @BartvanIngenSchenau. That actually does make sense, however, is the codebase then doomed to always violate some principle? Say if a refactor was deemed a good thing, would it be better to capture things that could be fixed partially in smaller PRs or let them land while violating a principle and then bulk fix them later? Is it valid to question why the violation is happening in a PR that didn't set the violation, but just adheres to a pattern that's already in place?

Comment: @pailhead: No, the codebase is not doomed, but such refactors will not be easily accepted from random committers. To refactor the codebase in such a way, you would first need an agreement among the maintainers that it is a good idea (and it helps your case if you have a good reputation among them) and a plan how to  go about it (i.e. one big commit, or multiple small ones; which area's to tackle first, etc.).

Comment: One point that can't be just showed aside is the amount of work to do. To refactor to comply with some guidelines is *work*. Not just reformatitting, do the regression testing (might need to create many tests for this as part of the job) and fix any fallout. And for contributors working on the package it is work to get (re)acquainted with the new code. Unless the advantages solidly outweigh this, there is no *engineering* reason to do the work. "If it ain't broke, don't fix it".